# Angular UI Bootstrap Tooltip tooltip-is-open weird behaviour

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use a tooltip directive from Angular UI Bootstrap inside one of my own directives. I want to manually toggle tooltip's visibility using `tooltip-is-open` attribute that Bootstrap Tooltip provides. [Angular UI documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip) states:

```
tooltip-is-open <WATCHER ICON> (Default: false) - Whether to show the tooltip.
```

So I assume it watches on the attribute's value. And so I want to bind a scope variable `tooltipIsOpen` to the attribute, hoping that changing `tooltipIsOpen` value in my directive's `link` function would toggle the tooltip visibility.

The behaviour that I get is weird.

1. If I bind `tooltipIsOpen` value as an expression: `tooltip-is-open="{{ tooltipIsOpen }}"`, the tooltip doesn't appear at all, though I see that the DOM is updated properly (`tooltip-is-open="false` switches to `tooltip-is-open="true"` and back again to `false`) in reaction to mouse events.
2. If I bind `tooltipIsOpen` value as a variable: `tooltip-is-open="tooltipIsOpen"`, the tooltip apears properly after the first mouse event, but then doesn't react to any further events, staying displayed all of the time with no way to hide it.
3. The working solution I found is bind `tooltipIsOpen` as a function call :`scope.tooltipIsOpenFun = function() { return tooltipIsOpen; }` and `tooltip-is-open="tooltipIsOpenFun()"`, or as an object property: `tooltip-is-open="tooltip.isOpen"`. Only then the tooltip works fine - shows and hides all of the time.

I suspect it's related to how AngularJS watchers work, also to the difference in how JavaScript primitives and objects are treated when assigning the values. Still I can't understand it.

**Question**

Can somebody explain to me step by step why the solution *1* doesn't work and *2* works only once?

**Directive template (for method *2*)**

```
<div uib-tooltip="Tooltip message"
     tooltip-is-open="tooltipIsOpened">
   ...
</div>
```

**Directive link function**

```
module(...).directive(..., function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            /* Stop further propagation of event */
            function catchEvent(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            };

            function showTooltip(event) {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.tooltipIsOpened = true;

                    /* Hide tooltip on any click outside the select */
                    angular.element(document).on('click', hideTooltip);
                    elem.on('click', catchEvent);
                });
            };

            function hideTooltip() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.tooltipIsOpened = false;

                    /* Remove previously attached handlers */
                    angular.element(document).off('click', hideTooltip);
                    elem.off('click', catchEvent);
                });
           };

           scope.tooltipIsOpened = false;

           elem.on('mouseenter', showTooltip);
           elem.on('mouseleave', hideTooltip);
        });
```

Comment: what about toggleTooltip example on link you gave? 1st way is just incorrect, 2nd way you should use apply in click, not when you register event.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov: Why is the 1st way incorrect? Why do you say I should use `$apply()` inside `click` in 2nd method? It is used, only inside a `click` handler `hideTooltip()`.

Answer (score 3):

1st way is incorrect because this directive expects variable name, not variable value. So correct:

```
<div uib-tooltip="Tooltip message" tooltip-is-open="xxx">
```

Or correct (you pass {{}} but then you pass not value of variable but value of variable that stores variable name):

```
<div ng-init="yyy='xxx'">
    <div uib-tooltip="Tooltip message" tooltip-is-open="{{yyy}}">
```

2nd way astually works somehow:
http://plnkr.co/edit/OD07Oj2A0tfj60q2QKHe?p=preview
But it is very strange - how user supposed to click outside element without triggering mouseleave event?

The thing is that you do not need all this, just:

```
<button uib-tooltip="Tooltip message" trigger="mouseenter"
     tooltip-is-open="tooltipIsOpened">
   hello
</button>
```

works fine.

3rd way: if you see that 'open' does not work, but 'smth.open' works that usually means you faced 'dot issue' - you can not change parent scope variable from child scope directly, but you can change variable properties. There is a lot of examples and explanations of this issue.

Comment: You wondered how user would be able to click outside an element without first trigerring `mouseleave`. It's possible in my app, because the element (I simplified it to `<div>` to make this example cleaner) is a *select* component with a drop-down menu. After clicking element in a drop-down menu, it disappears and you're outside the *select* element without trigerring `mouseleave`.

Comment: Can you give me some example of the 'dot issue' related to angular watchers?

Comment: What is a `trigger` attribute in your last example?

Comment: What does a `trigger` attribute do?